how to modify a non json data into a specific format in python?
I have an input file that contain the data like this --
{
0/2 = [
"test_server_101:99904"
,"test_server_103:99907"
,"test_server_106:99906"
];
1/2 = [
"test_server_203:99906"
,"test_server_303:99902"
,"test_server_403:99906"
];
}

And I am trying to convert this into --
{"test_server_101:99904": '0' ,"test_server_103:99907": '0' ,"test_server_106:99906": '0' "test_server_203:99906": '1' ,"test_server_303:99902": '1' ,"test_server_403:99906": '1' }

As I can't control the input and this is not a proper json data or not proper dictionary as the key doesn't have single or double quotes. It is difficult to process input data. Till now I have tried below code but it is not working as per my requirement. Any suggestion in this regard?
server_data = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  print(lines) 

  for line in lines:
    parts = line.strip().split(" = ")
    print(parts)
    value_str = value_str.strip()[1:]
    for server in server_list:
      server_name, *port = server.strip().split(":")
      server_data[server_name] = key
print(server_data)


I assume there are other programs out there that can read this file...., do you know how they do it?

Which program you are referring, I didn’t catch your question clearly.
Are you suggesting jsonlint?

@VIPINKUMAR I think the question is, presumably, some other program is consuming this format (why else is it being produced this way?) so how exactly does that happen?

I have no idea where this data comes from or how this file may be used in your system. But it appears to be intentionally formatted - and my guess is that it is intended to be parsed by other programs.

I have no idea about the downstream and upstream of this data.

You can use regex to get each group and corresponding servers, then remove unnecessary characters and split the servers in each group into a list:
import re

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    input_data = file.read()

matches = re.findall(r"(\d+)/\d+ = \[(.*?)\];", input_data, re.DOTALL)

output_dict = {}

for group, servers in matches:
    servers_list = servers.replace("\n", "").replace('"', "").split(",")

    for server in servers_list:
        output_dict[server] = group

print(output_dict)

{
    "test_server_101:99904": "0",
    "test_server_103:99907": "0",
    "test_server_106:99906": "0",
    "test_server_203:99906": "1",
    "test_server_303:99902": "1",
    "test_server_403:99906": "1",
}

